# how to make search algorithms better in php

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am creating job portal website so I need search functionality in that. I want to make search engine better in my website. 
In database, "jobs" is a table  where the attributes are:  job_id,job_title, location,exp, tags 
I am using following code for searching.

```
  $que = mysql_query("select * from jobs where tags like '%{$search_keyword}%'");
```

It displays results. But it have some little bugs.
For example:
In "tags" I insert record that is `PHP Software developer Javascript HTML CSS`. (I am not inserting comma [,] between words for better searching). 
My question is, when I search "PHP" keyword it display that record successfully but when I search "PHP developer" it is not displaying that record.
I want to display both PHP and PHP developer according to that record. I need some other idea for that.

Comment: Do **NOT** use mysql_* functions, it's deprecated and marked to removal. Instead, choose to use mysqli or php data objects (PDO)

Comment: Use a specific text-search database; MySQL's text search functions are pretty bare bones. This is a bit too broad to answer in detail, but suffice it to say that there's no real magic tweak you can do in MySQL, but you should rather add another product which is specialised in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Full text` search. Research before using for better under standing.
[full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). 
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
-> WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('database');
```